# restaurant which has biggest number of orders sql

Tags: sql-server

I'm new here and I need little help. I have the table below, upon which I want to find which restaurant with address have a biggest number of orders.

I've started my query like this ->

```
select  count(addressOfRestaurant) 
from Restaurants 
where addressOfRestaurant = 'Adress1' and orders = '1'
```

but this only count the result for one address. How to determine here in one query(count) the orders for another restaurants, and returns which one have biggest number of orders? In column orders 1 (means restaurant have order) and 2(restaurant doesn't have order)

```
+---+---------------------+--------+
|id | addressOfRestaurant | orders |
+---+---------------------+--------+
|1  | Adress1             | 1      |
|2  | Address55           | 2      |
|3  | Adress1             | 1      |
|4  | Adress789           | 1      |
+---+---------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide atleast the expected result.

Comment: @Ullas  expected result is addres with biggest number of orders

Answer (score 0):

Order by the `orders` and take only the first record

```
select top 1 addressOfRestaurant 
from restaurants
group by addressOfRestaurant 
order by sum(orders) desc
```